# How to use the default background image for iPhone UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

How can I use the [default background image](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/art/ui_textview.jpg) for a UIView?

Comment: The stripes? That's the default for grouped UITableViews

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
theView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
```

Comment: On the iPad this color is solid gray.  How do you get stripes on the iPad?

Comment: You should use UIColor's +colorWithPatternImage:

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) class:

```
[yourview setBackgroundColor:
  [[UIColor alloc] 
     initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourpattern.png"]]];
```

I always prefer using Interface Builder and just put a UIImageView occupying all UIView and send that UIImageView to back though...

Comment: There is a memory leak.  The code should be: [yourview setBackgroundColor:
  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourpattern.png"]]];

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Interface Builder you can choose "Group Table View Background Color" in the inspector of your UIview.

i just found out this when I read the above answer to your problem (i was trying to do that exatly :P)